# Firebase limitToLast (Query) not parsing the response

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing a query to get an array from Firebase and everything works fine. The query is the following:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("results").child("mood")
    .child(Preferences.getUserId(this))
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
...
```

And I noticed the child() chain always returns a [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference) object. However, I wanted to use [limitToLast()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#limitToLast(int)) to get only the last element of this array. I didn't really understand why but it returns a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) instead of a DatabaseReference, but both have the addListenerForSingleValueEvent() method since DbRef extends Query.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("results").child("mood")
    .child(Preferences.getUserId(this))
    .limitToLast(1)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

The problem is that it's not parsing my response as it was with DbRef, and then I get an exception:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap
```

I looked into the HashMap and it's just a Map of my Object attributes as Strings but not parsed.

Why do Query and DatabaseReference have a different response/deserialization method?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** As per requested, that it the code to get the data. It's the same for both cases.

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    GenericTypeIndicator<List<Mood>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<Mood>>() {};
    moodList = snapshot.getValue(t);
    ...do stuff with moodList
```

Whereas `moodList` is a `List<Mood>`

Comment: None of the code you shared does anything with the DataSnapshot that would trigger this error. Please include the code that actually causes the problem.

Comment: From the limited information given
dataSnapshot.getValue(List); is the problem. You are getting a hashmap from the server but you want it to expect a list.

Comment: Just added the relevant code. I hadn't included it 'cause I didn't change it for the two cases.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Please look at my answer to see if you can offer additional insights.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the code for your `Mood` class or a sample of the JSON that is stored at location "mood".  I'm assuming that you have defined `Mood` as a POJO that satisfies the Firebase requirements for getters/setters and default constructor.  Also that the value stored at "mood" is a valid array of `Mood` elements.

When you modify your query with `limitToLast(1)`, Firebase returns a map containing the last `Mood` in the array. Perhaps you were expecting it to return a `List<Mood>` with length of one.  I don't find the Firebase documentation clear on this point.  Perhaps Firebaser Frank can provide more details.

To see more clearly what is returned with `limitToLast(1)`, you can modify your code like this:

```
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String,Object>) snapshot.getValue();
            Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: map=" + map);
        }
```

The output will look like this, where N is the index for the last value in your array:

```
onDataChange: map={N={<the fields of your Mood POJO here>}}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer qbix. Yes for you first paragraph. Yes, limitToLast() takes an Integer so it should return a List anyways, but the documentation is not very clear indeed. I've tested your code and I got the expected output, however this HashMap is not being converted to my Mood object. I didn't wanna have to mess with Gson/Jackson for something that Firebase should be doing already. It looks that for some reason Query doesn't deserialize objects, only DatabaseReference. I hope @FrankvanPuffelen can still help me on that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I still haven't got a solution for this old thread :(